# box-shadow around a .png logo, which isn't a rectangle

Tags: shadow, css, graphical-logo

Is it possible in any way to create box-shadows around a transparent image? For example, a logo has many corners and i want the shadow to be drawn around these corners. When I add some box-shadow, it will draw rect-shaped shadows.

Thanks

Comment: why not add them directly to the logo?

Comment: ive tried that, but the shadow will be rectangular. i want it to be shaped like the logo

Comment: I'm mean that you add them to the logo himself (with photoshop or similar programs)

Comment: I will try that, but it will be easier using css (if its possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, box-shadow can generate shadow only around the box of the element, which is always rectangular. There is CSS `filter` property that can generate shadows around non-transparent areas of the image (see http://demosthenes.info/blog/598/boxshadow-property-vs-dropshadow-filter-a-complete-comparison), but its browser support is still limited.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Click here for more information, an explanation and a demo:
http://demosthenes.info/blog/600/Creating-a-True-Cross-Browser-Drop-Shadow-Effect-With-CSS3-amp-SVG